# Do leaves leave?

Tags: etymology

Originally I thought there might be an etymological connection between "leaf" and "to leave". ("A leaf is the spot where a tree leaves (into the blue).")

But then I compared the two Etymonline entries, and found these interesting - but semantically contradictory - etymological roots:

- [leaf (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leaf&allowed_in_frame=0):

  > probably from PIE **leub(h)-* "break off"
- [leave (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leave&allowed_in_frame=0):

  > from PIE root **leip-* "adhere".

How did the verb *leave*, which ultimately derived from a PIE root meaning *to adhere* and then from the Old English *lǣfan* "to allow to remain in the same state or condition..." come to have a meaning of "to stop, cease, give up, relinquish..."?  How did this meaning evolve?

Comment: Leaves *leaf* (out).

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? What did it say?

Comment: @Hot Licks: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: *Act like a tree and leave* is a common pun.

Comment: @Clare: What would a dictionary tell me? "There is no etymological connection between 'leaf' and 'to leave'"? (Maybe it is a connection the author of the dictionary was not aware of. And only maybe there is a dictionary whose author was aware of the connection - if it exists.)

Comment: The pun of leaving trees doesn't answer my question, does it?

Comment: If you Google `define leave` it will give you the etymology.  Spoiler - they are not linked.

Comment: This site expects you to indicate what research you have done, so that we don't you things you already know. It's your responsibility to include as much relevant detail in your question as possible, and to proceed asking questions here with at least a minimum of research. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @HansStricker It would tell you what professional lexicographers have established about the etymologies of *leaf* and *leave*. If there's a known connection, it will describe it. If there is no known connection, then there is no known connection. In other words, for etymologies, the dictionary will tell you everything that is known, and is the best answer you can look for.

Comment: It might be the case that no one ever addressed this etymological question (even though this is not probable). In any case it might require rather advanced Google-skills to find the one who did. Typing "define leave" would definitely not be enough. (At least me, I cannot see at a glance from the Google results that they are definitely not linked.)

Comment: @Dan: You mention "the dictionary". Which one would you consult?

Comment: A very useful source is Etymonline.  For leaf, see [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=l&p=9&allowed_in_frame=0).  For leave, see [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=l&p=10&allowed_in_frame=0).  If you have a question after reading these two eynmologies, then ask again.  (Actually, I have a question, but I will leave it to you!)

Comment: @HansStricker Any one you prefer. Same as "what's the best car?". Any car can get you from A to B, but they all have characteristics above and beyond simple transport which may shape your own personal preference. For example, the OED has a great reputation and lists entries in chronological order, but it isn't free to access. So your choice.

Comment: @ab2: Thanks for the hint to Etymonline. Comparing the two entries, I found these interesting - but semantically contradictory - etymological roots:
LEAF: probably from PIE *leub(h)- "break off"
LEAVE: from PIE root *leip- "adhere". What does this mean?

Comment: @ab2: Was this the question you left to me?

Comment: Maybe this is why "to leave" means "to stay" and "to go away"?

Comment: What I see from Etymonline is that leaf and leave do not have the same roots.  leaf comes from the PIE root *leub(h) -- to peel off, strip or break off.  Leave comes from the PIE root *leip -- to stick, adhere.  So far, OK.  Then we look closer at leave -- Old English laefan "to allow to remain in the same state or condition...; allow to survive...." and then a meaning related to leaving things to heirs.  (continued in next comment)

Comment: cont from preceding comment: Ok, I can vaguely see that.  But then, ca 1200, it meant also "to go away, take one's departure, depart from, leave behind."  Then after 1200 it meant "to stop, cease, give up, relinquish, ...discontinue....".  This is a far journey from "to remain in the same state, to continue."  What were the major branching points in this journey of the meaning of "leave" from to let remain to discontinue?  Ironical that the last development in the meaning of leave happens to mean the same as the PIE root of leaf -- to break off -- which is why you asked your first question.

Comment: It seems to me that the original question has been lost in a flurry of 3rd-party edits.  Shouldn't those editors ask their own question instead?

Comment: @HotLicks it was not edits by 3rd parties per se. It was OP's comments edited into the question body by others. And yeah, they added a pinch of salt, too.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oxford Dictionary Online, *[leave](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leave)* (as in 'to leave') comes from:

> Old English *lǣfan* ‘bequeath’, also ‘allow to remain, leave in place’ of Germanic origin; related to German *bleiben* ‘remain’.

And the other one is from:

> Old English *lēaf*, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch *loof* and German *Laub*.

Even so, 'leave' as in tree isn't spelt like that - it's leaf for singular and leave**s** for plural.  Just another irregular English plural!

Answer (score 2):

Many words in English that end with the letter "f" have either an optional or required plural form that changes the suffix to "ves."  This doesn't imply etymological roots shared with homophones that likewise end in "ves."

Consider [these numerous examples](https://howtospell.co.uk/plural-ves-rule):

> - calf - calves
> - half - halves
> - knife - knives
> - leaf - leaves
> - loaf - loaves
> - life - lives
> - wife - wives
> - shelf - shelves
> - thief - thieves
> - yourself - yourselves
>
> Some words can have both endings ves or s:
>
> - scarf - scarfs/scarves
> - dwarf - dwarfs / dwarves
> - wharf - wharfs / wharves
> - handkerchief - handkerchiefs / handkerchieves

*Oxford English Dictionary* describes this phenomenon under "Form History" for ***leaf***:

> In Old English as a strong neuter the word is typically unchanged in the nominative and accusative plural (in Northumbrian also with vocalic ending); unchanged plurals are sometimes still attested in early Middle English, but are quickly supplanted by the -s plural. The stem-final inherited voiced fricative was devoiced word-finally in Old English, but voicing was preserved before the vowel of the inflectional endings (although the consonant is written f in both positions). **The resulting variation in the paradigm is continued in modern standard English in the distinction between the stem forms of the singular and plural** (forms in regional varieties show analogical levelling in both directions).

However, this derivation of the plural form generally has no relationship with homophonic words.  In the case of "leave" as in "to depart," OED offers a distinct derivative chain.

**Leave**:

> Origin: A word inherited from Germanic.
>
> Etymology: Cognate with Old Frisian *lēva,* Old Saxon *lēvian* (Middle Low German *lēven*), Old High German leiben (Middle High German, early modern German *leiben*), Old Icelandic *leifa,* Old Swedish *leva* (Swedish regional *leva*), Gothic *-laibjan* (in *bilaibjan* : see *beleave* v.) < **an ablaut variant (o -grade) of the same Germanic base as *live* v.1 and *belive* v.1**

A similar comparison can be made with the related words "live (verb)" and "lives" as plural of "life," which have an etymological relationship, albeit a distant one.

**Live (verb)**:

> Origin: A word inherited from Germanic.
>
> Etymology: Cognate with Old Frisian *libba* (West Frisian *libbia*), Old Dutch *libben* (Middle Dutch *lēven,* Dutch *leven*), Old Saxon *libbian, libban* (Middle Low German *lēven*), Old High German *lebēn* (Middle High German *leben,* German *leben*), all showing a similar semantic range, Old Icelandic *lifa* to live, to remain, Norn (Shetland) *liva, lava* to live, Old Swedish *liva, leva,* (runic) *lifa* to live (Swedish *leva, †lefva* to live; the sense ‘to remain’ is expressed by the prefixed verb *kvarleva, †qvarlefva*), Old Danish *livæ, levæ* to live (Danish *leve*), Gothic *liban* to live < **an ablaut variant (zero grade) of the same Indo-European base as *belive* v.1 and *leave* v.1 Compare *life* n.**

**Life**:

> Cognate with Old Frisian *līf* life, body, person, Old Saxon *līf* life, body (Middle Low German *līf, lief* life, body), Old Dutch *līf* life (Middle Dutch *lijf* life, body, person, Dutch *lijf* body), Old High German *līb* life, body, way of life (Middle High German *līp, līb* life, body, German *Leib* body), Old Icelandic *líf* life, body, Old Swedish *lif* life, body (Swedish *liv* life, body), Danish *liv* life, body < **an ablaut variant (e-grade) of the Germanic base of *live* v.1 (zero grade) and *leave* v.1 (o-grade).**

---

Leaf, on the other hand, stands apart completely from "leave," "live," or "life."

**Leaf**:

> Origin: A word inherited from Germanic.
>
> Etymology: Cognate with Old Frisian *lāf* leaf, foliage, Old Dutch *louf* leaf (Middle Dutch *loof* leaf, foliage, Dutch *loof* foliage, also (now regional: southern) leaf), Old Saxon *lōf* foliage (Middle Low German *lōf* foliage), Old High German *loub* leaf, foliage (Middle High German *loup* leaf, foliage, German *Laub* foliage), Old Icelandic *lauf* leaf, foliage, Old Swedish *löf* leaf (Swedish *löv* leaf, foliage), Old Danish *løff* (Danish *løv* foliage), Gothic *laufs* leaf, *lauf* foliage, further etymology uncertain, perhaps < the same Indo-European base as Old Russian *lupiti* (Russian *lupit′*) to peel, strip off, undress, rob, Polish *łupić* to peel, strip off, rob, Serbian and Croatian *lupiti* to peel, strip off, strike, knock, Lithuanian *lupti* to peel, skin, *laupyti* to tear off, and perhaps further related to the Indo-European base of Early Irish *luib* plant, Old English *lybb* (medicinal) drug, poison, charm (see *lib* n.1) and perhaps also classical Latin *liber* inner bark of a tree, bast, book (see *library* n.1).

Comment: But what about 'leave'? You didn't address that.

Answer (score 0):

Leaves have been leaving in autumn since c. 1200.  From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=leave):

> Originally a strong verb (past participle *lifen*), it early switched to a weak
>       form. Meaning "go away, take one's departure, depart from; leave behind" 
>       (c. 1200) comes from notion of "leave behind" (as in *to leave the earth* "to
>       die;" *to leave the field* "retreat"). From c. 1200 as "to stop, cease; give
>       up, relinquish, abstain from having to do with; discontinue, come to an 
>       end;" also "to omit, neglect; to abandon, forsake, desert; divorce;" also 
>       "allow (someone) to go."